# Looking for another way to say this phrase

Tags: phrase-request

Say two people are talking about relationships **A** and **B**.

**A** is complaining to **B** that her relationship isn't going well because she and her boyfriend have many differences, that they do not have much in common.

**B** turns to **A** and says **"Someone might have all the things that we like but if they lack one thing then the relationship doesn't work out. They have to be a complete package."**

I think **B's** phrase is clunky and "A complete package" may not even be the best term to describe someone with all the qualities we like. Can anyone change this phrase and show me how to say the same thing in a less clunky way?

Comment: The idiom is "the complete package".

Comment: So there isn't another way to say that but that way?

Comment: B sounds like a very shallow person.

Comment: Hahaha, I think B is telling the truth sometimes one thing might ruin everything they have to be the complete package. @Michael Harvey

Answer (score 2):

As @SamBC says, you use *the*, not *a*. I don't think it sounds clunky; it's a common idiom. See Wiktionary for other expressions that are more or less synonymous: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whole_package

> whole package
>
> real deal
>
> total package
>
> whole nine yards
>
> whole shebang
>
> whole enchilada
>
> whole kit and caboodle

etc. Some of these might sound silly in general, especially when talking about a person (I probably wouldn't describe a person as "the whole kit and caboodle", for example).

See also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mister_Right , where you can find synonyms for "the perfect guy," in case this is what you have in mind:

> Mister Right
>
> Prince Charming

etc.